# Template: Incompatible list iterators

Tags: c++, list, templates

I have already implemented an overloaded Shift operator, which needs an output stream as a parameter. In another class I was working on this function, which returns the output stream for the overloaded operator.

This class contains a list with vehicles and I want to return a stream containing the names of these vehicles.

```
std::ostream& classname::outputprint(std::ostream& outputstream) const
{
    typedef std::list <Vehicles*>::iterator itType;
    itType it3;
    outputstream << std::setw(9) << name;

    for(cVehicles.begin() = it3; cVehicles.end() != it3 ; ++it3) 
    {
        outputstream << std::setw(4) << (*it3)->getName();  
    }
    return outputstream; 
}
```

In the header file, the Container is declared like this:

```
std::list<Vehicles*> cVehicles;
```

When I try to start the program I get the error: 
"Expression: list iterators incompatible"

Can someone explain to me why I get this error and how to fix this?

Furthermore I tried to change the for loop to this:

```
for( it3 = cVehicles.begin(); cVehicles.end() != it3 ; ++it3)
{
...
}
```

Here the programm does not compile at all and I get the error: 
"No '=' operator matches these operands". How can a simple shift have such an impact on the program?

I would appreciate any kind of help, thanks in advance!

Comment: change to `typedef std::list <Vehicles*>::const_iterator itType;`

Comment: What is `class::outputprint` supposed to mean? Anyway, is `cVehcles` a data member of a class whose member function you're attempting to show?

Comment: cVehicles is the list container. The declaration is above, its elements are vehicle pointers. 
class::outputprint returns the outputstream, which will be used to overload the "<<" operator.

Comment: Thank you very much Piotr. Why does this fix the error?

Comment: `class` is a keyword. You can't use it like that.

Comment: I just wrote it there for demonstration purposes, sorry i forgot that. Just think of an arbitrary name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `cVehicles` is a member variable it is then `const`.  You need a `const_iterator` to iterate it.

Second problem is that you inverted your assignment in the for loop in your function.

The final error you get is because of the iterator issue.  `begin()` returns a const_iterator, which can't be assigned to an `iterator`.  The other way is OK, but not const to non-const.

Comment: So in the for loop the iterator variable has to stand on the same side?
E.g. for( it1= cVehicles.begin(); it1!= cVehicles.end(); it1++) is ok!
but 
for( cVehicles.begin() = it1; it1!= cVehicles.end(); it1++) 
and for( it1= cVehicles.begin();  cVehicles.end() != it1; it1++)
are not ok?

Comment: Further why is cVehicles const? I just declared a private list container. Sorry but I never faced a const_iterator until now.

Comment: 1st and third are fine.  You can't assign to an rvalue so second is out.  cVehicles is const because the function that's using it is const and I'm assuming it's a member variable.  If it's not then I don't know--you didn't share that code.

Comment: cVehicles is declared in the "private" section of the class, so it is const, ok